# Rails Social Links Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to store user's social profile links: facebook, youtube, instagram, etc. Is there a gem that has this model already set up, or should I create my own?

If I have to create my own I'd create a polymorphic model/migration and re-use the shareable links across users, businesses, events, etc. Since these links are usually small each column would be a string data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much information you're gonna store, think you could just add these columns directly to user model (like "facebook_url", "twitter_url"), for example. But if it's something more complex, you could create another model and do the relationship.

something like:

```
rails g model SocialNetwork name:string
```

then a table for the nxn relationship between user and social network:

```
rails g model UserSocialNetwork user:references social_network:references profile_url:string
```

And any information you could possibly need. Then, on your `User.rb`:

```
has_many :user_social_networks
has_many :social_networks, through: :user_social_networks
```

and on your `SocialNetwork.rb`:

```
has_many :user_social_networks
has_many :users, through: :user_social_networks
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: I think I'm going to stick with a polymorphic relationship, but I def appreciate seeing your view on the matter. Glad to know there isn't a web-spread standardized way of doing this (via a gem) too.